# Can not echo entire line to file

Tags: command-line, bash

I can not figure out how to get the following line echoed to a file.
Only part of it makes it into the file.

```
echo perl -e "printf(\"%.1lf%%\n\", ($reserved_block_count * 100.0 ) / $block_count);">>Show_Percent_Reserved_Blocks.sh
```

When I run the script below this, I get

```
andyk_~/Downloads$ Show_Percent_Reserved_Blocks.sh
/home/andy/bin/Show_Percent_Reserved_Blocks.sh: line 2: Block: command not found
/home/andy/bin/Show_Percent_Reserved_Blocks.sh: line 3: Reserved: command not found
syntax error at -e line 1, near "/ )"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

#!/bin/bash
Block count:              421958912
Reserved block count:     4219589
perl -e "printf(\"%.1lf%%\n\", ($reserved_block_count * 100.0 ) / $block_count);"
```

Comment: Which part makes it into the file? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Your edits seem to be about different issues, namely that you've got two non-command lines in the file, and a syntax error in the Perl command. Please ask new question, and make sure to clarify what you're expecting to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that as you've used double quotes, the variable references (`$reserved_block_count`, `$block_count`) are being expanded in the current (invoking) shell environment; you need to quote the whole thing with single quotes around:

```
echo 'perl -e "printf(\"%.1lf%%\n\", ($reserved_block_count * 100.0 ) / $block_count);"' >>Show_Percent_Reserved_Blocks.sh
```